# Can you tell me what tense is: "if + simple past, would + infinitive"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tenses

> She hugs and smiles thinking if Arjun wasn't so greedy he would be alive today.

It is easy to understand , *if he had not been greedy he would have been alive today*. But, what does the above mean?

Comment: In this instance they mean the same thing. The right grammar for this sentence is clearly a *mixed* conditional: *if Arjun hadn't been so greedy, he would be alive today*. This is because he was greedy in the past, and the counterfactual statement applies to the present. But if you think you can only use three kinds of conditionals, you have to choose type 2 or type 3 for this sentence, neither of which is exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If Arjun wasn't so greedy he would be alive today* is an example of a syntactic construction that is often called the *second conditional* or *conditional 2*. The verb in the *if-clause* (the *protasis*) is in the simple past tense, while the main clause (the *apodosis*) contains the modal *would* plus a bare infinitive (in this case *be*).

One use of the second conditional is for present counterfactuals (statements about the present that are contrary to the truth):

> If you didn't smoke so much, you wouldn't have such a nasty cough (but
>   you do smoke, so you do have a nasty cough).
>
> If Arjun wasn't so greedy, he would be slim (but he is greedy, so he
>   is not slim).

On this basis, the statement *If Arjun wasn't so greedy, he would be alive today* implies: *but he is greedy so he is not alive today*. This is clearly nonsensical, since you cannot be greedy without being alive.

Assuming that Arrjun is indeed dead and greed resulted in his death, the sentence needs to be constructed as follows:

> If he had not been greedy, he would be alive today.

This is a so-called *mixed conditional* because it mixes the past perfect of the verb in the *if-clause* (a prototypical conditional 3 protasis) with *would* plus a bare infinitive (a prototypical conditional 2 apodosis).

As an aside I am interested to know the source of the sentence in question. As well as the semantic issue discussed above, it uses *hug* intransitively, whereas *hug* is normally followed by an object.

Comment: It's the last sentence in the story plot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jannat_(film)

Comment: @Mari-Lou. Thanks, not sure why it didn't occur to me to Google the sentence myself! The rest of the article, apart from one or two small problems, is in good English, so my supposition that the writer of the offending sentence was a non-native speaker is unproven.

Comment: then there is indeed a mistake in the sentence of the wikipedia?

Comment: #Anubhav Singh. Yes, but the problem is one of semantics, not syntax.

Answer (score -1):

From EduFind.com:

> The given sentence is an example of  **TYPE 2 CONDITIONAL** sentence.
>
> The type 2 conditional is used to refer to a time that is now or any
>   time, and a situation that is unreal. These sentences are not based on
>   fact. The type 2 conditional is used to refer to a hypothetical
>   condition and its probable result. In type 2 conditional sentences,
>   the if clause uses the simple past, and the main clause uses the
>   present conditional.
>
> More Examples-
>
> If you **went** to bed earlier    you **would** not be so tired.
>
> If it **rained**  you **would** get wet.
>
> If I **spoke** Italian    I **would** be working in Italy.
>
> If Arjun **wasn't** so greedy he **would** be alive today.
>
> The second sentence which you are referring to is a **Type 3
>   Conditional**
>
> The type 3 conditional is used to refer to a time that is in the past,
>   and a situation that is contrary to reality. The facts they are based
>   on are the opposite of what is expressed. The type 3 conditional is
>   used to refer to an unreal past condition and its probable past
>   result. In type 3 conditional sentences, the if clause uses the past
>   perfect, and the main clause uses the perfect conditional.

Refer to [this](http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/conditional/) site for more details on the conditional sentences.

Comment: It appears that you copied this answer from http://www.edufind.com/english-grammar/conditional/. You're using someone else's work without giving the author credit. This amounts to plagiarism, and is [not welcome on Stack Exchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Remember to answer **in your own words** and use external references to **corroborate,** always adding the correct formatting and a prominent attribution when quotng other sources. Thanks!